# LINQ expression to get difference from 2 list with a property

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have 2 list with Properties

```
public class Lookup
{
public int SlNo{get;set;}
public int StoreId{get;set;}
public int ItemId{get;set;} 
public string Name{get;set;}
public int Price{get;set;}
}
List<Lookup> current;
List<Lookup> history;
```

i want to get a new list

```
List<Lookup> changes;
```

Where `changes` contains items from `current` with a difference in Price property on items in `history`.
Is there any LINQ expression like `JOIN` or `INTERSECT` to filter it out?
Or do I need to manually iterate through all items?
If it's `JOIN` how can I do it on 2 properties `ItemId` and `StoreID` (combination of these 2 is unique).

Comment: Yes, they are called (*gasp*) [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx)...

Comment: Not sure why this question got a load of upvotes. You could find a clear answer to this in seconds by searching online.

Comment: @GlenThomas I hope u see the edit in question . I have troubles to get items with change since i have combination of properties as unique key. It would be nice if you can share some links for research

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
changes = (from c in current
           join h in history on c.Id equals h.Id
           where c.Price != h.Price &&
           c.StoreId == h.StoreId
           select c).ToList();
```

Comment: HOw can i mention 2 properties in inner join. Since in my case ID in not the primary key

Comment: I cant mention Id=Id in join since they are not going to be the same anyway

Comment: So what is the joining condition? You said 2 properties, now you say the `Id` is not going to be the same, so how can it be a part of the join if they are not the same?

Comment: StoreID and ItemID is the unique combination . Id is basically Database id in case of history_list  and Slno only [always starts wuth 1 ] in case of current_list

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Lookup> current = new List<Lookup>();
        List<Lookup> history = new List<Lookup>();

        List<Lookup> changes= new List<Lookup>();

        current.Add(new Lookup() { Id = 1, Name = "sdf", Price = 20 });
        current.Add(new Lookup() { Id = 2, Name = "asdf", Price = 30 });
        current.Add(new Lookup() { Id = 3, Name = "bsdf", Price = 40 });

        history.Add(new Lookup() { Id = 1, Name = "sdf", Price = 10 });
        history.Add(new Lookup() { Id = 2, Name = "asdf", Price = 30 });
        history.Add(new Lookup() { Id = 3, Name = "bsdf", Price = 10 });

        changes = (from cur in current join his in history on 
                  cur.Id equals his.Id where cur.Price != his.Price select 
                  new Lookup() { Id = his.Id, Name = his.Name, Price = his.Price }).
                  ToList();
```